# LSTM sequence2sequence translation using keras

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm

I am trying to build a LSTM sequence2sequence translator.
this part of the code is for learning:

```
num_encoder_tokens = 5000
latent_dim = 100
num_decoder_tokens = 5000

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(33,))
encoder_embedding = Embedding(num_encoder_tokens, latent_dim)
x = encoder_embedding(encoder_inputs)
x, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(x)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(30,))
decoder_embedding = Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, latent_dim)
x = decoder_embedding(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
x, _, _ = decoder_lstm(x, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(x)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.summary()
# Compile & run training
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
# Note that `decoder_target_data` needs to be one-hot encoded,
# rather than sequences of integers like `decoder_input_data`!
encoder_input_data = enc_in_final
decoder_input_data = dec_in_final
decoder_target_data = dec_out_final2
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=3,
          validation_split=0.2)
```

after training the model, I need two other models for encoder and decoder in inference mode which are as follows:

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_input = Input(shape=(30,))
x = decoder_embedding(decoder_input)
decoder_output, dec_state_h, dec_state_c = decoder_lstm(x, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [dec_state_h, dec_state_c]
decoder_output = decoder_dense(decoder_output)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_input] + decoder_states_inputs,
    decoder_output)

decoder_model.summary()
```

the encoder model works in inference mode:

```
encoder_model (enc_in_final[0:1])
```

but the decoder does not work:

```
decoder_model.predict([decoder_embedding(dec_in_final[0:1]), 
                      encoder_model(enc_in_final[0:1])[0], encoder_model(enc_in_final[0:1])[1]])
```

or

```
decoder_model(decoder_embedding(dec_in_final[0:1])+
                      encoder_model(enc_in_final[0:1])[0], encoder_model(enc_in_final[0:1])[1])
```

ValueError: Layer "model_61" expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 30, 100),

could anyone help me?